# How can i do an http-request with a post method to an api in Angular 9

Tags: angular, api, httprequest, postman

This is the first time I'm trying to do that and I don't know exactly how to start, if someone can guide me that would be very help full. I'm trying to do a login and if i want it to work a i have to do an http request with a post method to the API and will return me the information i need, but when I tried said Error 404 with URL, I tried with `Postman` and said other error that i will let below . **I'm not telling that someone have to do it for me , just need someone to tell how can i start**

- This is the `API`https://devapi.shocklogic.com/v1.0/:key/Users/login/
- To make the petition to this endpoint i have to send this token in the header `Token` Token-App': '7875d82ca05f8ba818011eb04a890c20cb44c52e'
- Also i need to send three params `Key`, `Identifier of the person` and `Password`

***Error that `Postman` said***

```js
{
    "type": "error",
    "message": "please make sure your meet the following field requirements",
    "check": 0,
    "passed": false,
    "requirements": [
        [
            "Identifier",
            {
                "is_required": true,
                "requires_value": true,
                "min_length": 1,
                "max_length": 150
            }
        ],
        [
            "Password",
            {
                "is_required": true,
                "requires_value": true,
                "min_length": 1,
                "max_length": 60
            }
        ]
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here's a sample code doing post request

```
let headers = new Headers({'Content-Type': 'application/json'});  
headers.append('Authorization','Bearer <your auth here>')
let options = new RequestOptions({headers: headers});
const body = { username, password }; // will depend on how your api will accept
 return this.http.post(APIname,body,options)
  .map(this.extractData)
  .catch(this.handleError);
```